# Does Relay.js support isomorphic server-side rendering with multiple sessions?

Tags: graphql, relayjs, isomorphic-javascript, isomorphic-relay

Last time I checked, Relay.js did not support session-based NetworkLayer (only one NetworkLayer could be used at the same time).

Thus, queue-hack (https://github.com/codefoundries/isomorphic-material-relay-starter-kit/blob/master/webapp/renderOnServer.js#L66) was required to support multiple sessions. It cannot be used in production as each render is completely blocking another render (including data fetching).

What's the current status on this issue?
Where can I follow the progress (github issues) and possibly help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is the GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/558) you're looking for, and great progress has been made on making most of Relay "contextual" at this point. See that issue for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 0.6 [`isomorphic-relay`](https://github.com/denvned/isomorphic-relay) (which `isomorphic-material-relay-starter-kit` uses under the hood) supports per HTTP request network layers, allowing to pass session data on to GraphQL server. And the important thing is that it uses isolated Relay store for each request, thus no user could see another user's private data.

Example usage:

```js
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  // Pass the user cookies on to the GraphQL server:
  const networkLayer = new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer(
    'http://localhost:8080/graphql',
    { headers: { cookie: req.headers.cookie } },
  );

  // Pass the network layer to IsomorphicRelay.prepareData:
  IsomorphicRelay.prepareData(rootContainerProps, networkLayer).then({ data, props } => {
    const reactOutput = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
      <IsomorphicRelay.Renderer {...props} />
    );

    res.render('index.ejs', {
      preloadedData: JSON.stringify(data),
      reactOutput
    });
  }).catch(next);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the problem is in relay.JS which means you should start on their GitHub page if you want to help.